# Why does Groovy perform floating point arithmetic this way?

Tags: groovy, floating-point

Trying out floating point arithmetic in Groovy. Have no idea why/how/what groovy is doing behind the scenes to cause these different types of behaviors?

```
double point2 = 0.2
double point1 = 0.1
double point3 = 0.3

assert point2 + point1 == point3 // false, as expected
   |      | |      |  |
   0.2    | 0.1    |  0.3
          |        false
          0.30000000000000004    

float point2 = 0.2
float point1 = 0.1
float point3 = 0.3

assert point2 + point1 == point3 // false, as expected
   |      | |      |  |
   0.2    | 0.1    |  0.3
          |        false
          0.30000000447034836

def point2 = 0.2
def point1 = 0.1
def point3 = 0.3

assert point2 + point1 == point3 // this returns true  
assert 0.2 + 0.1 == 0.3 // this returns true
```

I thought it had to do with BigDecimal but then I tried this.

```
BigDecimal point2 = 0.2
BigDecimal point1 = 0.1
BigDecimal point3 = 0.3

float point4 = 0.4

assert point1 + point3 == point4
   |      | |      |  |
   0.1    | 0.3    |  0.4
          0.4      false
```

What is causing this behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @tmyklebu no this is not duplicate of this question; while the first half would indicate that, as the asserts are phrased wrong, the question here is about the (implicit) type casts of groovy for "floaty" numbers.

Comment: @cfrick: I see.  You're right; this is about the type of an apparent floating-point literal.  Please forgive my itchy trigger finger; I saw `0.1` and `0.2` and `0.3` and said "Oh God; not again."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your `def`:s there are `BigDecimals`

```
groovy:000> p1 = 0.1
===> 0.1
groovy:000> p1.getClass()
===> class java.math.BigDecimal
```

And `equals` fails for comparsion between BigDecimal and the native float/double

```
groovy:000> p1.equals(0.1f)
===> false
groovy:000> p1.equals(0.1)
===> true
groovy:000> p1==0.1f
===> false
groovy:000> p1==0.1
===> true
```

Not sure yet, why `==` works for [Dd]ouble.

```
groovy:000> p1.equals(0.1d)
===> false
groovy:000> p1==0.1d
===> true
```

My guess would be, that it's burried in `DefaultTypeTransformation.compareToWithEqualityCheck`.  As both sides are Number:s.

Comment: I figured that out and added more to the question.

Comment: Okay, but why does equals fail for comparison between BigDecimal and native float/double? So I can compare a double to a BigDecimal but not a float?

Comment: actually I think you found a bug. My assumption would be that the BigDecimal is wrongly converted to a double for the comparison. I opened http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-7238 to track this